# search firstname from combination of lastname+", "+firstname using linq

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

i have written a stored procedure which returns me Customer Name in below format

```
LastName+", "+FirstName
```

i have assign it to Class of properties like below.

```
Customer = DbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<SearchEmployeeCDTO>("exec GetCustomerDetails").AsQueryable().ToList();
```

now i want to search the lastName like below i have done for Customer companyName

```
if(CompanyName!=null && LastName==null)
Customer = Customer.Where(c => c.CompName.Contains(CompanyName)).ToList();
```

please suggest how i can search for the LastName from combination of lastName and FirstName format

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
if(LastName!=null)
  Customer = Customer.Where(c => c.CustName.StartsWith(LastName)).ToList();
```

Comment: Or so :) if(CompanyName!=null && LastName==null)
  Customer = Customer.Where(c => c.CompName.Contains(CompanyName) && c.Name.EndsWith(LastName)).ToList();

Comment: my sql queries is like select lastName+", "+firstName as CustName from Customer. so my headace is how to find lastname data from it as when i write code customer.where(c=>c. then i dont get name for lastname here)

Comment: I might still be misunderstanding... My thinking is that if your CustName field is always formatted to start with the LastName part then you should be able to filter on CustName.StartsWith(LastName) ...

Answer (score 0):

if you try to check the values which another list contains the same or not then you can use this : (if you retrieve these as different properties of the generic list element)

```
bool b = your1stList.Exists(c=> c.firstName == your2ndList.firstName ,
                               c.middleName == your2ndList.middleName ,
                               c.lastName  == your2ndList.lastName)

if ( b == true) 
{ 
  MessageBox.Show("You already have this Customer"); 
}
```

this is a good way to retrieve all properties without any concatanation activity..Saves you from some headaches in futural queries ;)

In the other hand, if we continue from your query then you need to get the value of lastname + firstName into a string and use String.Split(",") function to put in a string array then if the word lastName+firstname check the array[0] index for the lastname and array[1] for the firstname  .

Choose which way you want..